# pylint error on calling base class ctor when base is abstract

Tags: python, pylint

Some cases classes should *not* call the constructor of their super class, like those inherited from abstract classes:

```
class Father:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self):
        self.salary = 700
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"my salary is {self.salary}"
print(Son())
```

Still, my legacy code contains a linter that complains about that:

```
$ pylint3 --disable=too-few-public-methods,missing-docstring main.py 
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module main
W:  5, 4: __init__ method from base class 'Father' is not called (super-init-not-called)
```

Is there any way to convey this fact to pylint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Father` class is abstract you should not have an `__init__` (well except if the init does something then you should call it) and you can explicitly make it inherits from ABC like this:

```py
import abc


class Father(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def interface(self):
        ...


class Son(Father):
    def __init__(self):
        self.salary = 700

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"my salary is {self.salary}"

    def interface(self):
        print(repr(self))


class BadSon(Father):
    """interface not implemented here"""


print(Son())
print(BadSon())
```

pylint understands what's going on:

```
a.py:26:6: E0110: Abstract class 'BadSon' with abstract
methods instantiated (abstract-class-instantiated)
```

But when you launch with python there's an error too:

```
my salary is 700
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(BadSon())
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BadSon with abstract methods interface
```

See [the documentation for the abc module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)